# Remove last character of a string ONLY if its an "s"

Tags: php

I'm attempting to write a code that will remove the last character from a specific string **ONLY** if the last letter of that string is an "s

## **$string Values**

```
Parts
Sealless Tools
Strap
```

**Substring** will remove the last letter; however, it will also remove the p from strap which is undesired.

```
substr($string,0,-1)
```

**pregreplace** removes the last s from each word.  It would turn Sealless Tools into Sealles Tool which is undesired.  Maybe there is a different expression that I can use?

```
preg_replace("/s\b/", "", $string)
```

**I searched google** but couldn't find an exact answer to removing last word of a full string only if its the letter s.  All the results were for individual words.

Comment: try `rtrim($str, 's')`

Comment: `rtrim($string, 's');` Though it will remove all trailing `s` characters; or `preg_replace('/s$/', '', $string)`

Comment: @Fabian `rtrim()` will fail is there are more than one `s` and the end, but it will works for the most of time I suppose :)

Comment: This will also remove the trailing `s` from words that actually end in `s` of course, like *oesophagus*, so if you're attempting to merely get the singular from the plural, this isn't the correct approach - especially if you ever need to support other languages... works well enough as a hack on a string you're about to chuck into a search query though (except for words like *boxes*).

Comment: @CD001 - Yeah I realize that.  Its for background code that I'm working on so that is something that I am aware of.  None of the words thus far run into any conflicts; however, if I ever run into that conflict, I'm just going to have to come up with another solution.  But it did get me out of a bind in what I was attempting to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some options...

```
1) $string = preg_replace('/s$/', '', $string); // slight modification to yours which limits to trailing 's'

2) $string = rtrim($string, 's'); // note: will remove 1+

3) $string = substr($string, -1) === 's' ? substr($string, 0, -1) : $string;

4) $string = $string[-1] === 's' ? substr($string, 0, -1) : $string; // php 7.1+ only
```

Comment: I agree.  I like the one liner codes rather than multiple steps

Answer (score 4):

You could use `substr()` to check the last letter before to remove it :

```
if (substr($string,-1) == 's') // get/check the last letter
    $string = substr($string, 0, -1); // remove last letter
```

Answer (score 1):

why using regexp here? RegExps are made for more complicated problems. Here you can simply use:

```
if($string[strlen($string)-1] === 's'){
    $string = substr($string, 0, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
$string = rtrim($string, 's');
```

The only risk here is if you've got a string with multiple letter s on the end, like 'Toolss', that becomes 'Tool' instead of 'Tools'